# Sending direct messages with message buttons from a slack app

Tags: slack-api

I have a slack app.

With webhooks I can use message buttons but I can't send direct messages.

As a bot user I can send direct messages but I can't use message buttons.

I want to send direct messages that contain message buttons. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct. In fact you can both use webhooks to send direct messages (incl. interactive buttons). And you can use interactive buttons with bots (and send direct messages). I have tested both and they work just fine.

**Webhook**

In order to send to direct message with an incoming webhook you need to provide the `user_id` (e.g. `U12345678`) of the user for the direct message as `channel`. Use the "channel override" feature as decribed [here](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#sending_messages) in the official documentation.

**Bots**

Make sure you meet all the requirements for interactive button, e.g. you need to have a Slack app and active the interactive buttons. You also need to have the correct scope set. The official documentation about interactive buttons actually refers to bots when talking about scopes. See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#readying_your_application_for_message_buttons).

Comment: Sadly the documentation for webhooks says the following:
You cannot override the default username, icon, or channel for incoming webhooks attached to Slack apps. Instead, these values will stubbornly inherit from the associated Slack app configuration.

Comment: That is true, but only for webhooks created via Slack app. You can also create webhooks by installing them from the App Directory, which then includes the ability to override channel and user name. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884185/4379151)..

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can send direct messages as a bot or using webhooks. I would also like to add that you can test out Erik's solution in [RapidAPI here.](https://rapidapi.com/package/Slack/functions/postMessage?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=SlackFunctions_postMessage) I've linked you directly to Slack's postMessage endpoint.

There you should see something like this:

[image]

Just write in your access_token, which channel/user you'd like to send the message to, your message, and click test. You'll see a detailed JSON response and you can generate a code snippet of the API call to paste directly into your project.